# Can I Register a Specific Domain to be Run in an Application?

Tags: c#, url-scheme

Similar to being able to register a custom scheme to launch a specific application, I would like to register a specific domain name to launch an application.  For example, if I launch a URL of https://my.domain.com from a link in my e-mail, I would like it to launch my application, which will keep the links I click in separate tabs.

Basically, I want to have a container program that is the sole application that can view https://my.domain.com.  This is because I will have several tabs open at one time on this web site and I want to keep them separate from the standard browser.  I already have this container program working manually, but I want to force Windows to use it any time I open a link with that domain name.

Comment: In the Windows registry, the mappings are from file extensions (.jpg) and schemes  (foo://, mailto://) to applications.  I'm not aware of any way to map subdomains that way.

Comment: The OS takes care of finding *something* that claims it can handle a particular scheme and then hands it over to that *something*. What that something does with it after that is not (currently) the OSes business. It leaves it to each scheme handler to understand the structure of any scheme it claims it can handle, including e.g if it contains a domain name and, if so, where that domain name appears within the structure.

Comment: ^ right, but for http and https the handler is your web browser.  The browser  does not ask the OS to look up any other handler for those it only asks the OS about schemes it doesn't process itself.  For Google you might be able to add an extension of some kind to intercept the URL and switch it to a different scheme like foo://